# Matrix Derivatives of Vector/Matrix Function wrt a Matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have the following formula

$F(X) = \text{vec}(Z^T(A-B-ZXX^TZ^T)ZX)$

and I want to take the derivative of it with respect to the matrix $X$. What is the proper way to do this? I believe the first two terms are

$(I \otimes Z^TAZ) - (I \otimes Z^TBZ)$ but having trouble with the third term. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Where vec is the vec operator, that takes a matrix and puts its contents into a vector column-wise.

$Z$ is $n \times m$

$A$ is $n \times n$

$B$ is $n \times n$

$X$ is $m \times m$

Comment: What shape is each variable? What does the $\operatorname{vec}$ do? Edit your clarifications into the question.

Comment: @J.G. I just edited them in. Thanks.

Comment: So $F$ is a vector with $M^2$ components?

Comment: Yes $F(X)$ is a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convenience, define some new variables.
$$\eqalign{
C &= A-B \\
Y &= Z^TCZ-Z^TZXX^TZ^TZ \\
f &= \operatorname{vec}(F),\quad x = \operatorname{vec}(X) \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of these new variable, calculate its differential,  and vectorize it.
$$\eqalign{
F &= Z^TCZX-Z^TZXX^TZ^TZX \\
dF
 &= Z^TCZ\,\color{red}{dX} -Z^TZ\,\color{red}{dX}\,X^TZ^TZX -Z^TZX\,\color{red}{dX^T}Z^TZX -Z^TZXX^TZ^TZ\,\color{red}{dX} \\
 &= Y\,\color{red}{dX} -Z^TZ\,\color{red}{dX}\,X^TZ^TZX -Z^TZX\,\color{red}{dX^T}Z^TZX \\
df
 &= (I\otimes Y)\,dx -(X^TZ^TZX\otimes Z^TZ)\,dx -(X^TZ^TZ\otimes Z^TZX)K\,dx \\
 &= \Big(I\otimes Y - X^TZ^TZX\otimes Z^TZ - (X^TZ^TZ\otimes Z^TZX)K\Big)\,dx \\
}$$
where $K$ is the [Commutator matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with the Kronecker product.

Finally, calculate the gradient matrix and revert to the original variables.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} 
 &= \Big(I\otimes Y - X^TZ^TZX\otimes Z^TZ - (X^TZ^TZ\otimes Z^TZX)K\Big) \\
 &= I\otimes(Z^TAZ-Z^TBZ-Z^TZXX^TZ^TZ) - X^TZ^TZX\otimes Z^TZ - (X^TZ^TZ\otimes Z^TZX)K \\
}$$